# How to override C lib functions like _sbrk with user-defined one?

Tags: c++, c, riscv, newlib

I want to use STL functions in C and C++ on RISCV that are provided by `newlib`. In order to use those I must replace the default implementation of `_sbrk`, `_read`, `_write` and some other functions. By default, `newlib` provides these functions and they use `syscalls` using RISCV's `ecall` instruction. However, I don't want to implement `ecall` instructions and instead provide new functions for them.

The problem is that I don't know how to replace a function in C and C++. So my question is basically, how do I override a function in C/C++? Specifically the `_sbrk` and other `syscall` functions.

Comment: Just define them. `in c/c++` There is no "c/c++". C is a programming language. C++ is a _different_ separate unrelated programming language. `By default, newlib provides` No, by default newlib doesn't provide them. You can _intentionally_ (not-by-default) link with a stub implementation, by doing `-specs=nosys.specs`.

Comment: @KamilCuk No it definitely auto provides them. This is my compile command "riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-g++  -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -T linkerscript.ld  -T "riscv64-unknown-elf/lib/ldscripts/elf32lriscv.x" -o bin.elf main.cpp". And it gives no linking error when using stl functions in main.cpp. I can also see it call recall in _sbrk in the disasembly. So it definitely auto provides them. Is there a way to prevent it from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Since I don't have a cross-compiler for RiscV, this example uses `malloc()` instead of `_sbrk()`. The principle is the same.*

1. Implement these functions yourself.

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   void* malloc(size_t size) {
       (void)size;
       return NULL;
   }
   ```
2. Then link that module to your other modules, and the functions will not be taken from the library.

   Let's say we have this simple program:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main()
   {
       printf("%p\n", malloc(23));
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   This is how I compiled and linked:

   ```
   gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -c main.c -o main.o
   gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -c malloc.c -o malloc.o
   gcc -Wall -Wextra main.o malloc.o -g -Wl,-Map=my_own.map -o my_own
   ```

The produced map file is not trivial, however, these are the relevant lines:

```
[--- lines cut ---]

 .plt           0x0000000000001020       0x20 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o
                0x0000000000001030                printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
 *(.iplt)

[--- lines cut ---]

 .text          0x0000000000001040       0x2f /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o
                0x0000000000001040                _start
 .text          0x000000000000106f        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../lib/crti.o
 *fill*         0x000000000000106f        0x1 
 .text          0x0000000000001070       0xc9 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/crtbeginS.o
 .text          0x0000000000001139       0x29 main.o
                0x0000000000001139                main
 .text          0x0000000000001162        0xf malloc.o
                0x0000000000001162                malloc

[--- lines cut ---]
```

As shown, `printf()` is taken from the library, but my own `malloc()` is used.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:
https://github.com/openhwgroup/cv32e40p/blob/master/example_tb/core/custom/syscalls.c
All required syscalls are there, malloc() is fully functional using this stub functions... Other stuff like printf() works as well, assuming the UART is at 0x10000000 (tested using qemu-system-riscv32 -machine virt)